# General questions about Poisson Point Processes

Tags: probability-theory

I am seeking to learn more about Poisson Point Processes. I will be learning on my own but I thought asking the questions here might speed up the process.

My questions are:

1- What does one need to define a poisson point process other than the intensity of the process itself? i.e, Is the intensity enough to define it?

2- I have read alot of papers that refer to the stationarity principle of the PPP,  can anyone explain what it is and why its useful?

3- Can one generate a PPP using MATLAB?

4- What other theorem specific to PPP such as the mapping theorem are important ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify, I'll assume you're talking about a homogeneous Poisson point process on $\mathbb R$.

1. Yes, the intensity defines the process.
2. Stationarity means that if you translate by a constant in space, the distribution stays the same.
3. Suppose you want a sample from the Poisson point process with intensity $\lambda$ on the interval $[0, L]$.  One way is first to determine the number of points in the interval, which is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda L$.  Then take a sample of that many points from the uniform distribution on the interval.  Here's some Matlab code:

```
function X = PoissonProcessSample(lambda, L)
    r = L*lambda;
    T = 0;
    U = rand;
    P = exp(-r);
    T = P;
    n = 0;
    while T < U
       n = n+1;
       P = P * r/n;
       T = T + P; 
    end
    X = sort(L*rand(1,n));
    end
```

EDIT: It is easy to modify this for the two-dimensional case.  Let's say you 
want a sample on the rectangle $[0,L_1] \times [0,L_2]$.  The number of points
is Poisson with parameter $\lambda L_1 L_2$.  The $x$ coordinates of the points are a sample of that many points from the uniform distribution on $[0,L_1]$ and the $y$ coordinates are a sample from the uniform distribution on $[0,L_2]$.

Comment: Thanks ! yes homogenous, I want to ask you further, how about 2D PPP, i.e points are on 2D plane, how do things change ? @Robert Israel.

Comment: @RobertIsreal Thanks for the help, when you say the number of points is poisson, do you mean to say that the number of points is itself a random variable?

Comment: and why is it that you choose a uniform distribution when generating the $x$ and $y$ coordinates? @robert isreal

Comment: Should the code have rand(L) instead of rand in the third line of your code? @robert israel.